# How to update Hundreds or a Thousand rows at once in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I would like to find a way in Postgres to update multiples rows in a single table all at once. The typical query is quite simple:

```
UPDATE mySchema.myTable SET myColumn = 'Foo' WHERE myColumn = 'Bar';
```

The problem I face is that many times there are over 30 thousand rows that need updating in one query, and it takes up to 25-30 seconds to perform one update if there are +30000 rows.

Additionally, this is not always being performed against the same table. There are literally hundreds of different tables across as many different columns where this time-consuming update may need to take place.

I've tried creating an index on the column right before its being updated in the hope that would make the update faster, but it had a negligible affect.

By the way, I am doing this in a java program using jdbcTemplate. I don't think the fact that its being performed in java has anything to do with the efficiency in this case, because I have attempted to same query directly pgAdmin and its just as slow.

I have heard that there are ways in Postgres to update hundreds or up to a thousand rows at once in a query like this, but I have been able to find a way to do that in my research.

I would be grateful to anyone who might be able to tell a way to make this more efficient. Thank you.

UPDATE: Here is an explain plan for query corresponding to the above:

```
QUERY PLAN
Update on myTable  (cost=0.00..20558.15 rows=30729 width=1566) (actual time=1466.010..1466.011 rows=0 loops=1)      
Buffers: shared hit=373636
   ->  Seq Scan on myTable  (cost=0.00..20558.15 rows=30729 width=1566) (actual time=7.287..39.930 rows=30729 loops=1)       
       Filter: ((myColumn)::text = 'Bar'::text)
       Rows Removed by Filter: 3
       Buffers: shared hit=20174
Planning Time: 0.074 ms
Trigger for constraint myTable_myColumn_fkey: time=845.070 calls=30729
Trigger myTable_history_trigger: time=14287.692 calls=30729
Trigger myTable_trigger_before_update: time=129.909 calls=30729
Trigger tr_myTable_10_before_i_u: time=240.634 calls=30729
```

Execution Time: 16618.486 ms

Comment: You have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Rather than work out how to make updating lots of rows efficient, realise that by changing all Foo to Bar you are actually only making *one* logical update. Structure your database to reflect this by instead of having the value Foo repeated throughout the table, have a foreign key to the value Foo and then you only need to update 1 row.

Comment: @Bohemian please assume that I cannot restructure my database. Yes, its inefficient. I can't address that. I cannot change the database. I cannot renormalize the tables. I can only work with what's there.

Comment: 1) You are already updating thousands of rows per your problem description: *it takes up to 25-30 seconds to perform one update if there are +30000 rows.* 2) One possible solution it to break the big update down into a series of smaller ones using an `AND` condition added to the `WHERE myColumn = 'Bar'` . 3) Add to your question the result of `explain (analyze, buffers) UPDATE mySchema.myTable SET myColumn = 'Foo' WHERE myColumn = 'Bar';` the next time you run of these queries. That may provide more information on what the choke point is.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I just added the explain plan to my question. Thanks

Comment: Well the time for that is `19.534 ms` and the numbers of rows is `1` so that is obviously not one of the problem runs.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry, I had set up the explain incorrectly. Please see new. By the way, I have to obfiscate some by changing names. Hopefully I did it correctly such that the plan makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I would say the smoking gun is: `Trigger myTable_history_trigger: time=14287.692 calls=30729`.  `select 14287.692/16618.486` = ~0.86 of the total time. I'm going to guess `myTable_history_trigger` is `FOR EACH ROW` and whatever function it is using is doing a lot of work. Is that correct?

Comment: The actual update takes 39.930 millisecond, next to nothing. Rest of the time is spent on the triggers, and myTable_history_trigger is by far the worst but the others are also pretty time consuming.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am trying to get some information back from the DBAs who own the DB to see whether anything can be done about that time-consuming trigger. I am grateful for your help so far.

Comment: Assuming the current triggers are `FOR EACH ROW` you might point them at [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), in particular `FOR EACH STATEMENT` which fires the trigger just once at the end of the statement so at the end of the action. In conjunction with this have them look at the `REFERENCING`  clause that allows you to access a transition relation that has all the rows affected.

Answer (score 1):

Do the update in chunks, of say 10K rows at a time, by repeatedly executing something like:

```
UPDATE mySchema.myTable SET
myColumn = 'Foo'
WHERE myColumn = 'Bar'
AND id < 10000 + (select min(id) from mySchema.myTable WHERE myColumn = 'Bar')
```

This will keep the log size per execution modest and not hog system resources.

Comment: Hi Bohemian. I could not get your example to work above (column "id" does not exist). I am not sure how to initialize that in SQL. Thanks

Comment: @Timothy you have not shown your table schema so I had to guess. Please show it.